# build my own CDN service

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cdn

I have two servers, both with self domain
1st www.myexample1.com
2nd www.myexample2.com

and now I would like to setup CDN of www.myexample1.com to www.myexample2.com

but I dont know how setup DNS or Apache that, so both servers served files for www.myexample1.com request

... I don't need solve databases, sessions or someting else... but I need know, how to do that both server will available as www.myexample1.com

Comment: This is probably more relevant on ServerFault, seems like an Apache question.

Answer (score 5):

**You cannot build a CDN with two servers.**

A real Content Delivery Network (CDN) has servers on several continents, and routes the end users to a server near him by means of TCP/IP Anycast, geo-aware DNS, HTTP redirects and HTTP proxying, or more likely combinations thereof.

Your question is vague to the point of being un-answerable. If you just want to have both servers serve files for `www.myexample1.com` without any high-availability, you could use [DNS Round Robin](http://www.google.com/search?q=dns+round+robin+site%3Aserverfault.com) for `www.myexample1.com`, and set up your second Apache to also answer requests for this hostname via a [name-based virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: +1 That's "BGP Anycast"; otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do DNS round-robin "load balancing". But for a simple CDN solution check out http://code.google.com/p/cirruxcache/

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a big question your asking, and not an easy one if your not familiar with DNS or Apache, but first can I ask what you're looking to achieve by using a CDN? Do you have a current issue you're working around by investigating a CDN?

It's not what I would call a CDN, but the quickest way to achieve want you have described is to have a caching proxy ([squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to name a common one) , which you point domain1 to. Then the proxy goes off to domain2 when it needs content it doesn't have in the cache. If a visitor hits the proxy and it already has the file they are asking for in cache, it will be served from there rather than domain2.